# Good documentation/book about Future

Tags: java, concurrency, future

Can anyone suggest a good documentation/tutorial/book about the [Future](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface in Java?

Comment: Please describe the prior research you have done in your question. What have you already found? Why are you not satisfied with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bible is [Java Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601).

Answer (score 3):

The [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) itself of the concurrent package is pretty darn good. I think it's one of the most beautifully javadoced code in JDK.

Answer (score 3):

[Concurrent Programming in Java(TM): Design Principles and Patterns (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201310090) by Doug Lea. This is the book by the author of java.util.concurrent package. Java Concurrency in Practice is a very good book, too.